# how do i put together my python code so that the menu option will run more than once?

Tags: python, list, function, methods

i would like the menu to run more than one but when it runs a second or third time i want the list of scores to be updated every time the program runs. the problem im having is after im done adding new scores to the list the new added scores does not show up the second time i run the program. im guessing that is because the list of scores updates within a while loop. does anyone know how to fix this? please help! and thank you!

Comment: Your post lacks proper formatting. Please edit to correct the indentation so that your code is displayed correctly.

Comment: This post is 12 hours old, its newest comment 9 hours, and no feedback from you. What's up?

Comment: Looks like homework. Also, I find it hard to believe you wrote the line that computes the std deviation, your prof will too. You might want to cite your source.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave comments yet so I am going to have to leave this in an answer.  First, is the indention in your post correct.  If it isn't it is because all lines that belong to the while loop need to be indented.  Also this is more of a formatting thing, but you should move your function definitions above all the code or put them in a separate file.  I also notice in your for loops that you do a lot of referencing to index which you do not need to do.  For example averageScores() could be written as follows:

```
def averageScores():
    s = 0
    for i in scores:
        s += i
    avgScore = s / len(scores)
    print("The average score is: " + str(avgScore))
```

I also notice that when you call addScores() under your elif clause, you are not actually storing the result to anything, you want that line to read `scores.append(addScores())`

Comment: thank you for your help but even after i added scores.append(addScores()) under the elif it still does not store the values into scores. because after i call the addScores() then try to call  averageScores() i get an error that says cannot divide by 0. the scores list still seems to be empty as it started off

Comment: That's because you also need to pass your scores array to averageScores().